# Why is my file being joined to its directory in the Error message?

Tags: python, faster-rcnn

`00157.jpg` is an image in the folder `images`

For a `FileNotFoundError`, I'd be expecting to see `'/host/Mask_RCNN/Kangaroo/kangaroo-master/images/00157.jpg'` where the `images` and `00157.jpg` are seperatd by `/`. However, in the error below, that's not the case. The image file seems to be "joined" to its directory.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/host/Mask_RCNN/Kangaroo/kangaroo-master/images00157.jpg'
```

I've provided the code below. I'd like to know the changes that I should make to the code in order to solve this, please.

P.S. I'm running the file on Jupyter notebook, in a docker container, if that helps.
Complete error message:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-383929dd479b> in <module>()
      1 # load an image
      2 image_id = 20
----> 3 image = test_set.load_image(image_id)
      4 print(image.shape)
      5 print(test_set.class_ids)

/host/Mask_RCNN/mrcnn/utils.py in load_image(self, image_id)
    357         """
    358         # Load image
--> 359         image = skimage.io.imread(self.image_info[image_id]['path'])
    360         # If grayscale. Convert to RGB for consistency.
    361         if image.ndim != 3:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/_io.py in imread(fname, as_grey, plugin, flatten, **plugin_args)
     59 
     60     with file_or_url_context(fname) as fname:
---> 61         img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
     62 
     63     if not hasattr(img, 'ndim'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py in call_plugin(kind, *args, **kwargs)
    209                                (plugin, kind))
    210 
--> 211     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    212 
    213 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/pil_plugin.py in imread(fname, dtype, img_num, **kwargs)
     33     """
     34     if isinstance(fname, string_types):
---> 35         with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
     36             im = Image.open(f)
     37             return pil_to_ndarray(im, dtype=dtype, img_num=img_num)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/host/Mask_RCNN/Kangaroo/kangaroo-master/images00157.jpg'
```

Code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

#Loading the model in the inference mode
model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", config=config, model_dir='./')

# loading the trained weights o the custom dataset
model.load_weights(model_path, by_name=True)
img = load_img("/host/Mask_RCNN/Kangaroo/kangaroo-master/images/00157.jpg")
img = img_to_array(img)


# detecting objects in the image
result= model.detect([img])

# load an image
image_id = 20
image = test_set.load_image(image_id)
print(image.shape)
print(test_set.class_ids)
# load image mask
mask, class_ids = test_set.load_mask(image_id)

print(mask.shape)
print(class_ids)
# plot image
pyplot.imshow(image)
# plot mask
pyplot.imshow(mask[:, :, 0], cmap='gray', alpha=0.4)

pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message, and also the one that matches your code (the file names are not the same).

Comment: @DYZ I've edited the question to include the complete error message with matching file names. I'm sorry for the confusion caused earlier.

Comment: What is `test_set`? `image_id = 20` and `image = test_set.load_image(image_id)` are causing the problem

Comment: There is likely more code somewhere else in your Jupyter notebook

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm not entirely sure as I'm just trying to run it based on this [ https://towardsdatascience.com/object-detection-using-mask-r-cnn-on-a-custom-dataset-4f79ab692f6d ] tds article which has an accompanying github repo at [ https://github.com/arshren/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/Transfer%20Learning%20Mask%20RCNN-Custom%20dataset.ipynb ]